# Disable QuickTime updates

Tags: windows, updates, quicktime

Is there a way to turn off QuickTime Updates aside from the steps:

1. Control Panel
2. QuickTime
3. Updates
4. Uncheck the checkbox

I’ve been searching through to the registry but no luck there. 
The main reason is because when I sysprep a computer that has QuickTime it gets the checkbox back.

OS: XP SP2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After using [ProcMon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) for a few minutes it seems there is no registry entry containing update preferences, it appears to be stored in a proprietary format in a file called **QuickTime.qtp** (QuickTime Preferences file).

It is located at:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\[username]\Local Settings\Application Data\Apple Computer\QuickTime
```

where [username] is the name of the user account.

First, turn off automatic updates on a system, copy the **QuickTime.qtp** file, and during sysprep you could have this file copied over to each computer's directory shown above.

Out of curiosity though, why are you putting yourself through this using sysprep? [WDS](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771670%28WS.10%29.aspx) is far superior in many ways. You can configure a "skeleton" computer just the way you like it, then image it and deploy it to multiple computers.

Comment: We use Ghost Enterprise to create images and need to sysprep a computer when Gathering them.
We also create a defult User account when creating our images will that cause any issues with the qtp file?
We run our systems under a 2003 Server domain.

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand the updates run based on a schedule in Windows Task Scheduler.

1. Click Start -> Programs -> Accessories -> System Tools
2. Click on Scheduled Tasks or Task Scheduler depending on your version of Windows
3. Find **AppleSoftwareUpdate** and click it
4. Hit Delete on your keyboard